# Setting a traceId with an existing value in Spring Sleuth

Tags: spring-cloud, zipkin

We have an application and where we are tracing the whole logs using a custom correlation header i.e. X-CID with a value as for example, 615b7eea-6d4c-4efb-9431-fcbba084ea3f. Recently we have integrated the Spring Sleuth with the train version as Greenwich.BUILD-SNAPSHOT in our application and using brave's Span and tracer to create trace and span ad sending it to Zipkin.

What we are looking for a mechanism where we can use or set the CID value as a traceId rather than using the auto generated one from Sleuth.

The rational behind is, we would like to make it uniform CID value to use or search in Zipkin UI rather than two different values i.e. CID value and Spring Sleuth traceId to trace the complete API calls.

Please note that, we would like to reuse the X-CID from request which is already supplied in the request header.

Are there any APIs to override this behavior or any alternate way to achieve this ?